# React app не запускается

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

Доброго времени суток господа. Не понимаю причину по которой лезет эта ошибка при npm start.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

лог ошибки:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v13.14.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~prestart: my-app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: my-app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\React\my-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\dosis\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Users\dosis\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\React\my-app
10 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\React\my-app
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v13.14.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

win7 x64
И node.js переустанавливал несколько раз и само приложение, уже что только не делал.

Comment: `````npm i`````?

Comment: проблема остается та же

Comment: Лучше в ответы написать.

Answer (score 1):

Исправил проблему

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
```